# I can't install 'pip' for python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, powershell, pip

I'm going trough the book Learn Python The Hard Way and i need to install pip.[(ex46](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex46.html),ex47) 
So i saved [get-pip.py](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py) on my computer and in powershell i did :

```
PS C:\Users\Toto\pip> python Get-pip.py
Downloading/unpacking pip
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip
Cleaning up...
```

but then when i try: PS C:\Users\Toto\pip> pip

i get this error:
`pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the s
pelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pip
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`

C:\Python27\Scripts\ is already on my path.

I can't figure this out. If some one could please help me.

note: i'm on windows 8 and this is with python 2.7

Comment: You probably need to add it singularly to the PATH environment variables

Comment: this may help http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/win/

Comment: nbro, how do you mean? pip itself? And in path or in PATH?

Comment: Try to import `pip` on the idle and see if you can do it...

Comment: I'm sorry but i'm really new to this. I don't really understand. Could you further elaborate?

Comment: In the `IDLE`, the Python interactive shell, that you use to test your statements, write this command: `import pip`.

Comment: Are you able to call `pip` from the command line now?

Comment: If you don't want to mess with PATH and assuming calling python works, you can use "python -m pip ..." instead of "pip ..."

Comment: nbro yes that works now, thanks. But i have the same error with nosetests now.

Comment: Thanks alot everybody i got it to work! :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Whenever I've installed pip on my Windows machine, it installs to my Python's Scripts folder:

```
c:\Python34\Scripts
```

So to get pip to run on the command line, I had to add that path to my PATH environment variable. You can get to those settings by doing the following (assuming Windows 7 or newer):

1. Right click My Computer and choose `Properties`
2. Go to Advanced system settings
3. Click on the `Environment Variables` button
4. Double-click the PATH (or Path) variable listed under `System variables`
5. Add `c:\Python34\Scripts` to the end of the list of other paths making sure that it is separated from the previous entry with a semi-colon

Restart your shell and try running pip. If it still doesn't work, you need to find out where pip got installed. In my Scripts folder, I have a `pip.exe` file. If you do not, then adding the `Scripts` folder to your path won't help. You'll have to figure out where it got installed and add that path instead.

Comment: Thanks alot, it works. I also have nose installed. But when i try to run a test, i get the same error as i had with pip. It's also installed in: C:\Python27\Scripts.
I cd to the right folder with the tests and then i type 'nosetests' in powershell. But it gives me the error. Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: perfect way of explaining stuff - helped me set it up!

Answer (score 0):

You can copy zklib in the odoo server folder and restart the odoo server and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

For windows users If the above solution does not help then make sure your python folder is in the right place to do so, go to the windows search bar and type python then right-click open location folder and copy the path and paste it in the environment variables

for more explanation check the following [link ]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i4yJi-cpwWk

Answer (score -1):

What you have to do is you have to first give your Python path then you have to give your Scripts path.

First delete that Scripts path and now click on new button copy the python path and paste it.

Second , click on the new button and copy the Scripts path and paste it.

Now, I think your problem will be solved.